# php mysql sql check query to validate pre registered card numbers

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have devised the following script below which atm checks if the username already exsits in our pre filed database.

Now i would like to check if that username has already filled out other details such as email/name or is not been claimed as such.

A real novice here any help would be greatly appriciated.

thanks

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table

if(isSet($_POST['username']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];

include("dbconnection.php");

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM {$prefix}users WHERE user='$username'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check))
{
echo 'OK';

}
else
{
echo 'INVALID CARD NUMBER';
}

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM {$prefix}users WHERE email='null''");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check))
{
echo 'OK';

}
else
{
echo 'Card already registered';
}

}

?>
```

Comment: `user='$username'` - don't do in this way. Don't use `mysql_`, read about `PDO` or `mysqli_` and sql injections

Comment: yh i thought about this but i am just doing a rough demo to see how it would then would have to get more help to tidy and secure it.

Comment: Do you want to check a user have registered their mail id or not? I mean the user who logging in.

Comment: yes that would work.. if a userid has their email registered no not loging in but to stop from reregistering. so only one email per userid can submit the form.